# How can I avoid this crosstalk issue?

Tags: voltage, battery-operated, crosstalk

I have cutout a piece of my PCB that generates the crosstalk (I measured with multimeter.)

[image]

In the middle I have a 3.3 V boost/buck converter which generates power for my ESP32. On the left there is a connector for the battery. The boost/buck converter should take its power from the 5V line. For debugging purposes, I added two via holes (B+ and B-) on the board to be able to switch on and off the battery connection. If I switch it off (let both vias float,) the 5 V line is 0 V and the regulator on the right puts out 0 V (as expected,) but I measure a voltage of 0.9 V on the 3.3 V transmission lines.

My first thought was that the two traces that I highlighted could be cross talking to each other (generating an electromagnetic field I think but don't know certainly,) but I didn't think this could be a problem because of my SIG-GND-GND-SIG stack up.

Does anybody have an idea what's going on and maybe recommend a better way to implement an on/off switchable B+ line

Comment: _"I measured with multimeter"_ How did you manage to measure crosstalk with a multimeter?

Comment: _"SIG-GND-GND-SIG"_ This wastes one of the inner layer from being Vcc. Any particular reason you went with two ground layers?

Comment: Also, the image looks unclear to me, you should have placed an arrow pointing to the problem area.

Comment: If you're using a multimeter's AC voltage measurement function then it is too slow to measure cross talk. If you're using the DC measurement function, DC cannot be crosstalk. In either case, something else is going on.

Comment: I measured a voltage of 0.9V on the 3.3V line, which should be 0V, so I assumed that there is some kind of crosstalk. I have read a lot about Stackups, and I choose that one, because to every SIG Layer is an adjecent GND layer, and Rick Hartley (YouTube) said, that VCC Layers are not neccessary.

Comment: You need to get yourself an oscilloscope.

Comment: Yes you are right definitely, but those are quite expensive. On top of that my knowledge to frequencies, EM Fields and this whole subject is very limited. I don't know if it's too early for one. Anyway, could you assume from the picture above, that the two highlighted traces (red and blue) are talking to each other from Layer 1 to Layer 4, can that be?

Comment: You have two solid copper planes, so crosstalk through the board (which is not what you're measuring with a DMM) is very unlikely. What problem are you having that caused you to search for crosstalk?

Comment: I assumed because there is no way that there could exist a voltage of 0.9V. The switch is literally off, and the 3.3V Line has 0.9V. The 5V is off, like intended. But how can there be voltage still on the 3.3V line?

Comment: You should post your schematic, the problem is more likely a voltage feeding through from elsewhere in the circuit. Also, are you powering the ESP elsewhere while taking this measurement? Is anything else connected to the board? USB cable perhaps?

Comment: It seems like you're using some terms in an out-of-context way. "Crosstalk", for example, is something which occurs between signal or data lines, but you're using it to apply to power lines. Similarly, "transmission lines" usually refers to the conductors which carry high-frequency signals or data, but you're using them to refer to your 3.3V supply traces.

Comment: Yeah my bad I'm a noob when it comes to this stuff